# Vue.js <keep-alive> in template for slot not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm working with a component that was built out called 'Stepper' it's a basic component that has the steps at the top to guide the user through a process. In this stepper we have a dynamic number of slots that are produced and we pass a component in to fill that slot.

Stepper.vue

```html
...
<div v-for="step in steps" :key="step.name">
  <div class="stepper-pane" v-if="step.name === currentItem.name">
    <slot :name="`${step.name}`" />
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Parent.vue

```html
...
<Stepper :items="steps"
  <template v-for="step in steps" v-slot:[step.name] :key="step.name">
    <keep-alive>
      <component :is="step.component" />
    </keep-alive>
  </template>
</Stepper>
...

<script lang="ts">
...
import Stepper from "@/components/Stepper.vue";
import Component1 from "@/components/Component1.vue";
import Component2 from "@/components/Component2.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "ParentComponent",
  components: {
    Stepper,
    Component1,
    Component2,
  },
  setup() {
    const steps = ref([
      {
        name: "step1",
        label: "Step 1",
        component: "Component1",
      },
      {
        name: "step2",
        label: "Step 2",
        component: "Component2",
      },
    ]);

    return {
      steps,
    }
  }
</script>
```

All in all everything is working. The component for each step displays, the steps increment so on and so forth. The issue we're having is that the `<keep-alive>` is not working. Every time you go back or forth in the steps the component re-renders and we're seeing the `onMounted` hook called. Granted we can pre-populate the form with some 'saved' data if needed but would be nice if we could get the `<keep-alive>` to work. We've also tried adding the `:include="[COMPONENT_NAMES]"` to the `<keep-alive>` as well, to no avail.

Edit: Updated code snippet with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<keep-alive>` is caching the dynamic `component`, but the `v-if` directive inside `Stepper.vue` removes the `div.stepper-pane` and its `<slot>` (thus destroying the current component before mounting the new one) based on `currentItem.name`, which leads to the behavior you're seeing.

One way to fix this is to refactor `Stepper.vue`, moving the list rendering into the default slot. To me, this makes sense because `Stepper.vue` only ever renders one step/slot at a time.

```html
<!-- ParentComponent.vue -->
<Stepper :currentItem="currentItem">
  <keep-alive>
    <component :is="currentItem.component" />
  </keep-alive>
</Stepper>
```

```html
<!-- Stepper.vue -->
<div class="stepper-pane">
  <slot />
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-keep-alive-with-v-for-components-rvwrz4?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FAllSteps.vue)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're not testing this in your development environment that usually has caches disabled. Therefore if you don't have a cached reference the keep-alive wont work.

`This means that Vue does not have to create a new instance every single time you switch components. **Instead, it just uses the cached reference whenever you come back to it**. Keep-Alive is what VueJS calls an abstract element – meaning that it does not render a DOM element nor does it show up as a component.`

Also you could have the cache disabled in the Console tools.

To be certain you can check this setting:

[image]

#another edit:

I have done some more research, and adding a key to your Keep-alive component

`<component :is="step.component" :key="UniqueIdentifier" />`

will help your vue-router understand that this component is changed.

Check out this other SA answer: [vue Keep-alive not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019923/vue-keep-alive-not-working/52428204)

Comment: Thanks. 1) can i disable caching in the dev environment to verify it is working? I verfied that i do not have caching disabled in dev tools and 2) we should have a cached version of the component I would think. We've defined a steps array as such: const steps = ref([{name:"step1", component: Component1},{name:"step2", component: Component2}]) where Component1/2 are the components that are imported into the Parent where the <keep-alive> is defined.

Comment: We went ahead and did a production build as well and rolled it out to our dev servers to see if it would work out there and the keep-alive isn't performing as expected with a prod build either.