# <b-form-file> does not keep the filename visible when switched to other components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I am new to Vue and using Bootstrap view for my form.
I am using b-form-file for uploading a file in component say Component2.vue and I am able to browse my local filesystem and select the file. The filename is seen in the b-form-file after the selection.
When I visit another component(Component1.vue) via the UI and come back to Component2.vue, the filename is not visible in the browse anymore. Although I have used v-model to bind it to the file and the bind is happening but the filename is not displayed in the b-form-file.

I want to keep the filename visible in the b-form-file as it is binded to 'file' throughout the session.
I am using b-form-file like this:

```html
<form>
  <b-form-file
    id="form-model"
    v-model="file"
    required
    placeholder="Choose a model..."
  ></b-form-file>
<form>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { file: null }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"visit another component"_? Are you using dynamic components or something like that, eg a tabbed layout?

Comment: I am using router links for both Component1.vue and Component2.vue. When clicked on any one takes me to its respective form. b-form-file which I am talking about is present in Component2.vue's form.

Comment: Why would you expect data to persist when you navigate away from the current router view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 2 <keep-alive> not working with <router-view> and key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898440/vue-2-keep-alive-not-working-with-router-view-and-key)

Comment: I'm using the b-form-file in tab view and it's the same. I don't change the route only switched to another b-tab. Did you found any solution ?

Comment: @EmilGeorgiev I have used <keep-alive> which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

well I was using tab view to display `<b-form-file>` and encountered the same behavior. As I was not using `<router-view>` so the `<keep-alive>` solution did not worked for me. I found a nice little trick by dynamically setting the placeholder prop of the `<b-form-file>` component to display the filename. The following code is pretty self-explanatory I think.

```
<template>
<b-form-file
  v-model="file"
  id="file"
  :placeholder="fileName"
  drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
  accept=".xlsx, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
/>
</template>

<script>
import {
  BFormFile,
} from "bootstrap-vue";

export default {
  components: {
    BFormFile,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
      fileName: "Choose a .xlsx file or drop it here...",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    file(newVal, _) {
      this.fileName = newVal.name;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```