# Vue3, vue-router, how to keep unused view mounted, with audio playback (more than keep-alive)?

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, keep-alive

**I want to use vue-router, but then keep a currently unused view mounted in the DOM.** Something like Vue's `keep-alive` but with just hiding the unused view, instead of unmounting it.

The reason is, **this view has an audio player in it, and I want to keep it playing**. On unmount, it's stopping. Here's how it looks currently:

```
<!-- To keep the audio within the media player component running, 
simply keep all components alive over route changes -->
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <keep-alive include="Play">
        <component :is="Component" />
    </keep-alive>
</router-view>
```

**I would like to replace the `keep-alive` with something like `keep-mounted` (but hidden).** How can I do that?

Notes:

- Of course I already have tried using Vue's `keep-alive`, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66297873/79485, and it's working as advertised. However, It's not enough, I need to keep the component mounted, not just kept in memory.
- I have found https://github.com/Akryum/vue-router-multi-view, but this is vue2 only.

Comment: Can you place the component outside of the `router-view`?

Comment: @Thomas I could, at least the audio element, which in itself has no visual representation. However I have some chrome to it, and I would doubt, that after coming back, the component could pick up the playing element's data again. And, I actually have multiple audio elements, depending on some state of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found **a solution for the specific problem at hand, being the interrupted audio playback.** As suggested by @Thomas I have placed the audio element completely out of the DOM, using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

Here's how I create the audio context with the element, right at component creation:

```
data: () => ({
    //...
    /** The audio context to use
    audioContext: new AudioContext({
        latencyHint: 'interactive',
    }),
    audioElement: document.createElement('audio'),
}),
```

I never add the audio element to the DOM, but use it with the received element handle as usual:

```
/** Handles the setup of the audio graph outside the mounted lifespan.
 * @devdoc The audio element is intentionally not added to the DOM, to keep it unaffected of unmounts during vue-router route changes.
 */
created() {
    this.audioElement.src = this.src;
    //.....
},
```

With this, although the VueJs3 view gets lifted from the DOM with `keep-alive`, the audio is unaffected of this.

I then subsequently destroy the audio context and the audio element at the `unmounted()` lifecycle event.

This works very well. You may review the complete code at https://github.com/suterma/replayer-pwa/blob/a5acd8dc3b5a277bca6d9baf9459fb70eea2e1a5/src/components/TrackAudioApiPlayer.vue